# Google Firebase auth emulator always logs out user, and not isolating from production

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I'm using Firebase auth, and my app is working fine. But when I run it in the emulator, I get a login event, followed immediately by a logout event (user=null). I am setting it up with `firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099')` as required.
I see this error in my Chrome dev tools log which may or may not be the cause:

> POST http://localhost:9099/www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=AIzaSyCwV8E9N0nw3euy7cJFhe-OY4j2iTuvXYZ 400 (Bad Request)

I do see the auth events in the emulator console:

> Received a signed JWT. Auth Emulator does not validate JWTs and IS NOT SECURE

so I know it's touching the auth emulator. But, I see sign-in events and user creations in my real Firebase auth console, not my emulator console -- so it seems like it's only halfway using the auth emulator. Is there some trick to getting this to work locally?

Comment: "*I get a login event, followed immediately by a logout event (user=null)*" - how exactly are you observing this?  Would you like to edit your question to share the [complete, minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I would love to try to cut it down to a minimal reproducer but I'm afraid that would take quite a bit of time, and since my app itself is working OK I can't spend that time right now. I'm hoping someone will recognize the symptoms and have an idea for me. As for how I'm observing it, I log the auth state change events as they occur.

Comment: I have prospect signup test suite that flakes due to a related console error that comes from the emulator auth.  ```Entry {
    level: Level { name_: 'SEVERE', value_: 1000 },
    message:
     'http://localhost:9099/www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIzaSyBVR7ji2BQzvcII6ScjGQ989vuvbfdSMWU - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)',
    timestamp: 1610218021850,
    type: '' },```

Comment: Are you using `firebaseui`? I think it might be related to https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/778